# Get rid of Vaadin Grid Pro minimum size

Tags: layout, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

So I have some `Grid`s that won't shrink to less than 10 rows.

This causes some layouts to overflow where they shouldn't.

How do I adjust the minHeight?

I tried

```
grid.setMinHeight("0");
```

but that doesn't do squat.

Comment: Perhaps you should post another Question asking specifically how to shrink a Grid to display less than 10 rows. Include a minimal [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `grid.setMinHeight("0");`

Setting min-height to "0" will never accomplish anything, ever. Everything that has a non-negative height has "at least a size of 0".

So I think you are confusing min-height with max-height. Max Height will do what you are asking for: Some smaller grids are okay as they are, but if a grid tries to expand to 1000px height, it is restricted by the defined max-height.

```
grid.setMaxHeight("500px");
```

Of course I don't know to what value exactly you want to set as max-height, so you might want to replace 500 with your desired value.

Comment: Duh, looks like I need a coffee. Thanks. :)